# Domain Driven Design: infrastructure concern or domain concern?

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I cannot decide whatever this is infrastructure or domain responsibility:

User can pass date range in url query, eg dateStart=2016-04-12 , dateEnd=2016-04-15. Based on that date range we return list of entities that have field createdOn between these two dates. To make this work correctly I must convert 2016-04-12 to 2016-04-12 00:00:00 and 2016-04-15 to 2016-04-15 23:59:59, is this conversion should be considered infrastructure concern ( and should be put in repository, or maybe application layer ) or bussiness rule ( and should be put in service or entity ) ?

Comment: Ideally you should have a service class or a library class that has all the commonly used function. For eg in this case a function called formatInputDate could be a function which you can use to format your date.

Comment: This seems to be a data constraint because your application rules allow the short ISO date format whereas your database only supports long ISO date format. So, it is a database function that should be put in the data access layer (or in stored-procedures/views, if you use those).

Comment: `DateRange` seems to be a pretty important concept. I'd model it as a value object that enforces date range rules. The boundaries of a date range would be defined by date values. The application service would receive the strings and create a `DateRange`. The `DateRange` would then be passed to the repository. The date formatting would then occur within the repository (delegating to date utility methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this conversion should be considered infrastructure concern ( and should be put in repository, or maybe application layer ) or bussiness rule ( and should be put in service or entity ) ?

As noted by plalx, `DateRange`/`TimeInterval` is likely an important concept on its own, and should be represented as a value type in your model.

Taking the user inputs that you get, and expressing them in the types represented by your model is an application concern.

Finding a list of entities that satisfy that constraint should be a repository concern.  It can be useful to make that constraint explicit in your repository contract - it serves to document what capabilities you need in the underlying stores.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Util` object (class), which would provide the converter method for you.
You have to decide about how would you use the format in your deepest layers (some kind of repository?). If that format is not the same as it would be shown on the application layer, than you'd have to use the conversation somewhere (I suggest the top of your backend API), but be ready to use validation inside the repository layer etc. as well.